# Why I can not I use the variable outside my function?

Tags: posts, id, query-variable

I am writing a little plugin, to extract the post ID and them use it for some queries.

Of course if I write:

```
function my_callback_function() {
    $aa = 'hello world!';
    echo $aa;
}
call_user_func('my_callback_function'); 
// returns: hello world
```

but if I write:

```
function my_callback_function2() {
    global $post; 
    // get post iD
    $aa = $post->ID;
    echo $aa;
}
call_user_func('my_callback_function2'); 
// returns: null... nothing
```

but if I call my_callback_function2 from the "add_meta_box" it works perfectly:

```
function _custom_meta_boxes() {

    add_meta_box('projects_refid', 'Post ID', 'my_callback_function2',
    'x-portfolio', 'side', 'high');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', '_custom_meta_boxes');
// returns the correct post ID: 5345
```

The question is: how can I use the $aa variable for a simple db query... or just something like: echo $aa; wherever I like?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the trivial question!

Augusto

Comment: are you sure `$post` already exists when you try to access it in your second example? your third example is hooked to an action that runs at a specific time. you can't access data before the thing that sets up that data runs.

Comment: Simply because *bare* php codes runs very early of the processing, before the `$post` object set

Comment: You shouldn't be using globals for metabox callbacks anyway - pass it as a parameter i.e. `function my_callback_function2( $post ) { /* Code without global */ }`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is order, the `$post` variable isn't available from the moment WordPress is loaded, it needs to process the request, put together a database query, and retrieve the post first. Time travel is necessary for your code to work as you expected.

Your themes `functions.php` and plugins will be loaded before this happens to give them a chance to have a say in the process, so if you attempt to use `$post` at that time, it will fail, we don't know what the `$post` is yet, that work hasn't been done.

The reason it works in the add metabox call, is because that action happens *after* the post is retrieved. This action happens in the future at a time when `$post` exists and is known, after the work needed was done.

I would suggest as a general rule of thumb that you do work inside actions and filters, and rely on common actions for this, such as the `init` hook, or the `admin_init` hook, etc

[See here for information on when hooks and important events happen, and when things are possible](http://www.rarst.net/wordpress/wordpress-core-load/)